# Zend Framework Configuration in Linux server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I am having problem with configuring `.htaccess` file Zend framework. In my local server it is working ok which is running apache and windows 7.

But When I trying to run it in live server it shows `403 Forbidden`

Here is my .htaccess configuration

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|media|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|css|js)
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `ALLOW FROM ALL` ?

Comment: do you mean into .htaccess file

Comment: yes. you can try to add it inside the .htaccess file and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Almost always the reason for this is that Apache user doesn't have read permission on those files.

Comment: So, Can I enable it. just by setting .htaccess permission to 777

Comment: Not only .htaccess, it's for all files in your application. You can do that using ACL (may not be available on VPS) or just chmoding.

Comment: it did not work, when I try to access using /public/ everything works fine

Comment: Well, you are meant to access it using /public. You can not access it using root application directory (but you can configure virtual hosts so you wont have to add /public all the time).

Comment: but this is live server, I don't have an access to apache directory

Comment: I got a bit lost. If you go to http://domain/your_application/public it works, but http://domain/your_application it does not (forbidden)? If yes, that's how it is meant to be.

Comment: .htaccess can be disabled then. There must be line (uncommented)
AccessFileName .htaccess
in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

I think if you simplify your `.htaccess` rules you can get things to work properly.

Since your Zend Framework `index.php` file is presumably in `public_html/public`, open `httpd.conf` or `httpd-vhosts.conf` depending on your configuration, and add `/public` to your `DocumentRoot`.

This way, `public` will be the web accessible directory and everything below it including the ZF application files will be protected.

After you make that change, replace all of your `.htaccess` file with the standard Zend Framework rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Also, make sure all of the following items are true as things may not function properly otherwise:

- Set `AllowOverride All` for your public_html directory in `httpd.conf`
- Chmod `644` for `.htaccess` and all PHP scripts, `755` for most directories
- `APPLICATION_PATH` in index.php is correct

Hope that helps.

Comment: the problem is that you can access httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf files only in local sever what if it is in live server(hosting). I cannot access this two files.

Comment: Secondly, even I direct to any files files it doesn't work. I just create test.php  file in root directory

Comment: In that case, move all the files (index.php, .htaccess) from `public_html/public` to `public_html`.  Move all the ZF files (`library`, `application`, `docs` etc) to one directory above `public_html`.  Then replace your `.htaccess` with the standard `.htaccess` file I posted above.